# I want to delete the data that the consumer has succeeded (nodejs + kafka)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to delete the data commit that the consumer has succeeded

File consumer.js

```
const { Kafka } = require("kafkajs")

run();
async function run() {
  try {
    const kafka = new Kafka({
      "clientId": "myapp",
      "brokers": ["localhost:9092"]
    })

    const consumer = kafka.consumer({
      "groupId": "notification",
    })
    console.log("Connecting.....")
    await consumer.connect()
    console.log("Connected!")

    await consumer.subscribe({
      "topic": "otp",
      "fromBeginning": true,
    })

    await consumer.run({
        autoCommit: false,
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
          console.log(`RVD Msg ${message.value} on partition ${partition}`)
          await consumer.commitOffsets([{ topic, partition, offset: (Number(message.offset) + 1).toString() }]);
        },
      });
      

  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(`Something bad happened ${ex}`)
  } finally {

  }
}
```

What functions do I need to add to the consumer?
Or do I need to add a function at File producer ?

Comment: I think this can help https://ondrej-kvasnovsky.medium.com/how-to-delete-messages-from-kafka-22c1e1de3600

Answer (score 0):

Records in Kafka are durable and persistent, based on TTL, and will not be removed once consumed.

Use a different message queue rather than a distributed log, if this is a feature you need